# No JUnit test report in sonar

Tags: junit, jenkins, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin

The unit test coverage is working but not the unit report, it tells me 0.

I have a multi module project in my sonar-project.properties I have these 2 lines defined :

```
# Tells SonarQube where the unit tests execution reports are
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports

# Tells SonarQube where the unit tests code coverage report is
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
```

When I check in jenkins logs I see this :

```
Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
- Analysing C:\Users\Administrateur\workspace\MyProject\ModuleA\target\coverage-reports\jacoco-ut.exec
- Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 8253 ms
```

Here path looks good but not for unit test reports :

```
- Sensor SurefireSensor...
- parsing C:\Users\Administrateur\workspace\MyProject\.sonar\sonar.projectKey_sonar.modules\target\surefire-reports
- Sensor SurefireSensor done: 0 ms
```

It looks into a .sonar/ directory at the root and not in the target/ directory of the module.

Any idea of the issue ? Thanks !